# How to not change directory when I use "Go to file"?

Tags: neovim, plugin-nvimtree

I'm using neovim and I have `NvimTree` installed.

When I press `gf` on a file path, it opens that import file but at same time, my `NvimTree` go to that file path too, so I have to `cd` back to the original path

How can I keep it in the same place always?

---

Edit 1:

With some debug, I've noted the issue only happens when I `gf` to a folder, it changes my `cwd`, like in my JS project:

```javascript
import MyReactComponent from '../components/MyReactComponent'

//instead of

import MyReactComponent from '../components/MyReactComponent/index.tsx'
```

For example:

I opened my nvim in `~/project1/`:

$ cd ~/project1
$ nvim

Pressed `gf` with cursor on the import `../components/MyReactComponent`

It shows the list of files under `MyReactComponent` directory, so I choose the `index.tsx` and press `enter` to open it

At this time, if I check `:pwd`, it return `~/project1/components/MyReactComponent` instead of `~/project1`

So my `NvimTree` and `Telescope` start to look at only in `MyReactComponent` folder.

Is this a default behavior for vim? How can I change it to always stay on the initial `cwd`?

Comment: Does only `NvimTree` change, or does the output of `:pwd` change? Do you have `autochdir` on?

Comment: When the case happens, my Telescope changes too, I'm almost sure it's about `NvimTree`, because when I switch back to `NERDTree`, the issue stoped.

Comment: I tried both (enabled and disabled) for `autochdir`, but it doesn't seems change anything

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I've updated the description with more details, hope it can make my question clearly

Comment: Your edit makes it sound like autochdir is on and you don’t want it to be. But there could be plugin autocommands